# Time for query in RavenDB is too long

Tags: c#, testing, time, ravendb

I have an example for testing time of `query` in `RavenDB`. So I use `Linq` to `query` and `StopWatch` for geting timings.

But when I run my code, timing seems too long (it is `2401 ms`) so I try to query by `Ranven Studio` and the result, timing is just taking `1 ms`. I don't know why it has much more different like that.

Ps: My database has 200 000 documents and i have `indexes` for that, of course.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Raven.Client.Documents;
using Raven.Client.Documents.BulkInsert;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class SupportCall
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDay { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDay { get; set; }
        public string Issue { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static char[] _buffer = new char[6];
        private static string RandomName(Random rand)
        {
            _buffer[0] = (char)rand.Next(65, 91);
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                _buffer[i] = (char)rand.Next(97, 123);
            }
            return new string(_buffer);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var store = new DocumentStore
            {
                Urls = new[] { "http://localhost:8080" },
                Database = "Test"
            }.Initialize())
            { 
                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    var sp = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    SupportCall supportCall = session.Query<SupportCall>()
                        .Include<SupportCall>(s => s.CustomerId)
                        .Where(s => s.Cost == 21821).FirstOrDefault();
                    Customer customer = session.Load<Customer>(supportCall.CustomerId);
                    sp.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(sp.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make the same query (actually, better use a different parameters, to avoid the cost of caching) and check again?

The most common reason for this to take so long is that you are paying for the first time connection and establishing of the document store setup.
The strange part here is that you are doing this on the local host, so I would expect this to be very fast, even on the initial call.

You can use Fiddler (change the url to be: `"http://localhost.fiddler:8080"` so it will capture it) to see what are the costs on the network.

I have seen stuff like that happen because of anti virus and packet inspection utils.